# Setting VLC drawable-hwnd still create a new window

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, vlc

[Here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) I read:

```
Embedded window video
      --drawable-hwnd=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
          Window handle (HWND)
          Video will be embedded in this pre-existing window. If zero, a new window will be created.
```

I get the window handle of my Qt5 QML application in this way:

```
QObject* m_rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
if(m_rootObject) {
    QWindow *window = qobject_cast<QWindow *>(m_rootObject);
    if(window) {
        WId wid = window->winId();
        qDebug() << wid;
    }
}
```

and then I launch vlc:

```
vlc --drawable-hwnd=395302 udp://@:1235
```

but it still creates a new window. I'm working on Windows 7.
Perhaps I'm not understanding what the documentation says?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an RTSP stream.

Setting

```
--drawable-hwnd=windowhandle
```

seems not to be sufficient.

It only worked after I also set

```
--no-embedded-video
```

My complete command line looks like

```
--no-embedded-video --qt-notification=0 --qt-auto-raise=0 --qt-start-minimized --no-qt-name-in-title --no-video-title-show rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/
```